# Gradle with Android ActionBar-PullToRefresh signing.properties

Tags: android, gradle

I'am new to Maven, Gradle, Ant and etc.

I'm tying out the [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). It uses Gradle, so I open `sample/stock/build.gradle` with my Android Studio but it is saying `signing.properties` is missing.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `samples/actionbarcompat/build.gradle` defines `props.load(new FileInputStream(file('signing.properties')))` and `.gitignore` ignores the authors copy of the file in the git repo.

You might want to [follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752646/release-signing-in-gradle-properties-for-android) to create your own `signing.properties` file. or [open in issue](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/issues) with the author to include an example in his `README.md`