# Android gradle signingConfig error

Tags: android

I try signing my Application like [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations).
I write my signingConfigs settings but I get "Could not find property" error.

This my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "Andy Warhol"
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                debuggable false
                jniDebugBuild false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.myconfig
            }
            release {
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                debuggable false
                jniDebugBuild false
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
            myconfig {
                keyAlias 'xxx'
                keyPassword 'xxx'
                storeFile file('xxx')
                storePassword 'xxx'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile files('libs/picasso-2.2.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    }
```

This is my error

> Gradle 'BulentTirasMobileApp' project refresh failed:
>   Could not find property 'myconfig' on SigningConfig container.

Answer (score 140):

Move your `signingConfigs` block to appear before your `buildTypes` block:

```
    signingConfigs {
        myconfig {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myconfig
        }
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
    }
```

You need to define the configuration before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, moving 'signingConfigs' manually above 'buildTypes' didn't work, but produced a different error. So, what I did is delete 'signingConfigs' section altogether and generated 'signingConfigs' via 'File'>'Project Structure' -> 'Signing Configs'.

[image: 'SigningConfigs' in 'Project Structure']

It automatically generated 'signingConfigs' and errors disappeared. It placed 'signingConfigs' like in a picture below

[image: build.gradle(app)]