# How to Debug an APK Signed Release? (Using VS Code for development)

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, visual-studio-code, apk

I am using **VS Code** for Ionic/Cordova development.
Due to some restrictions with Google Plus Login process the APK is required to be signed.

I have successfully signed and tested the application on Android using the **CMD COMMAND** *(jarsigner)*.

However that is stopping me from debugging the app and checking the errors using VS Code Console as I usually would when Running the app on device for debugging without signing.

I noticed a similar question here: [How to debug apk signed for release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release)

However it is describing the steps for Eclipse which i do not have and do not use.

**Any idea on how to Debug the signed APK using VS Code?**
*(I do not know if it is possible to sign the app using VS Code and launch it directly to device as what i do now is transfer the apk file manually to my device)*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512684/android-studio-does-not-sign-the-code-for-debug-build) it would appear that you can add a signing config to your debug build configuration in build.gradle. This should allow you to not worry about having to generate the release apk and trying to debug that. However if that doesn't solve the problem for you, you should be able to mark the release build with debuggable true and minifyEnabled false, then attach VS code to a running process on android.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have added already the <application android:debuggable="true". but what do you mean by attach VS Code to a running process on android?

Comment: It looks like you would also need to set that in what appears to be a sibling gradle file in the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) . Then looking at the github page for the vscode cordova tools in the image about a 1/4 way down the page there is picture of the debugging options and one of them is "Attach to running android on device". This is the github page: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova) Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks a LOT! actually your first comment was enough for me to solve my problem. I simply, just simply filled in the section of the Keystore signing in the build.gradle and that ALONE was enough for VS Code Start Debugging command to sign the app! now i can test Google Plus login fully using VS Code! Hope this helps someone else as well!