# Android avc denied rs485

Tags: android

I'm using an Android-based motherboard for a project, and this board has an integrated RS485 port. I want to connect to a different system via Modbus RTU over this port and read and write data from certain addresses. However, when I run the program I wrote in Android Studio, I receive the following message on the logcat screen. I contacted the manufacturer and they sent me 2 files and 1 jar file to sign the written APK, but I can't debug and test the program. I wonder if anyone has encountered this problem and can help me. The device is rooted.

> type=1400 audit(0.0:2178): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/ttyS5"
> dev="tmpfs" ino=11547
> scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c127,c256,c512,c768
> tcontext=u:object_r:serial_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
> app=com.syssoft.myapplication

Comment: Regular Android apps don't have access to `/dev/ttyS5`. Please describe exactly what 2 files you got and how you sign your APK with it. My guess is that they sent you the keys necessary to sign your app as system app (system apps may have access to `/dev/ttyS5`). So you have to properly set-up your project to use that signing key.

Comment: They sent me these two files. platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem my problem is that these two files are only used to sign the APK after it's built, but I need to be able to debug my program. I can't debug it without signing it this way. @Robert

Comment: Import the PEM file into a keystore file and configure your project to use it as key store for signing in debug and release mode. See e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/q/28512684/150978