# Ionic automatic Android app signing broke after Cordova/SDK upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic (1.6.4) project with the Android platform that had an ant.properties file with the following:

```
key.store=mykeystore
key.alias=myalias
key.store.password=mypass1
key.alias.password=mypass2
```

Previously, I could run `ionic build --release` and it would build the unsigned apk, then sign it and produce another apk.

Recently, I needed to add the org.apache.cordova.splashscreen plugin which complained about my older version of Cordova, so I upgraded to 5.2.0 from 1.5.0.  That, in turn, required I update my Android SDK to get Android 22. The Cordova build process seems to run fine.

```
[...all the previous steps...]
:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:assembleRelease
:cdvBuildRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**However, Ionic now only produces an unsigned release apk.**

Any suggestions on what could be causing the problem? Is there a log file I can check that might give me a clue? I know that even before when it worked, if the keystore was completely missing, it would just not sign it and pretend everything was fine (no error), so I thought maybe something similar was happening here and it was just suppressing an error.

**Version Details:**

```
cordova -v // 5.2.0
ionic -v // 1.6.4
node -v // v0.12.7
npm -v // 2.13.5
ionic.js // 1.0.1
```

Things I already tried:

- ant.properties and keystore are both still there
- `cordova platform upgrade android` ran successfully
- in ant.properties, pointing to keystore using an absolute path, relative path, and simply putting it directly in platforms/android without a path
- both `ionic` and `cordova` commands
- `build --release android` and `build --release`

Comment: Immediately after posting this I started digging around again for any logs, and discovered that apparently the build process has switched from using ant to using gradle.  Do I need to write some new configuration file for gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears at some point between those software upgrades, some piece of the puzzle switched from using ant to gradle for the build process.

Following the answers on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752646/release-signing-in-gradle-properties-for-android) I was able to find out what to do.

First, create a gradle.properties file and fill it in with the appropriate data:

```
storeFile=...
keyAlias=...
storePassword=...
keyPassword=...
```

Next, edit the gradle.build file and add the following:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

if (project.hasProperty('storeFile')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(storeFile)
}
if (project.hasProperty('keyAlias')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
}
if (project.hasProperty('storePassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
}
if (project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
}
```

Now it signs the release apk properly.

Comment: it's build.gradle not gradle.build... but when I open that file it says it's generated and not to edit it.

Comment: i tried editing the one in the cordova folder, but i get errors with these settings. `A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not find property 'release' on SigningConfig container.`

Comment: The initial problem was caused by updating a project started with Cordova 1.5 to Cordova 5.2. Now in 2016 we have Cordova 6.0.  It's pretty unlikely this is the exact problem you're having, unless you're also encountering a problem after updating Cordova for the first time since 2014.